# Hub Header vanishing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating an app with a hub page. Here's the relevant xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <Hub Header="My App">
        <HubSection Header="My drops" x:Name="DropsSection">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView x:Name="DropsList" Loaded="DropsList_Loaded">
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>

        <HubSection x:Name="FriendsSection" Header="Friends">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView x:Name="FriendsList" Loaded="FriendsList_Loaded">

                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>

</Grid>
```

Here's what it looks like in the designer:

[image: Here's what it looks like]

Yet when I run it on my Lumia 520, I see this - the header is missing!:

[image: Hub header missing!]

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Would need to give a width property for each hubsection for it to be visible 
Say `width="200"`
A header would scroll to a particular point only. Are you sure you want a Hub Page Not a Pivot page?